# Regex to match single quotes within double quotes (separately)?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a `regex` to match this (see arrows):

```
"this is a ->'<-test'" // note they are quotes surrounding a word
```

and other to match this?

```
"this is a 'test->'<-"
```

in JavaScript? (And then, say, replace them with double quotes?)

I want to match them separately with two regexs.

Comment: You want to match them seperatly or match every `'` in the string?

Comment: @alexchenco separately with 2 regexs.

Comment: `"this is a 'test' there is another 'test'"` So what happens here?

Comment: It's hard to know what you exactly want. You should either write more test cases or explain the use case. Note that this kind of problems is frequently better solved by more than just a simple regex.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R well, the two words will be treated separately. I guess it also needs word boundary.

Comment: *"I want to match them separately with two regexs."* - Why? And what if you get apostrophes mixed in there, e.g., `"this test's 'test'"` or `"The students' answers weren't 'right'"`?

Comment: @alexchenco Have you found a solution or do you still need some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first case :

```
var str = '"this is a \'test\'"';
var res = str.replace(/'/, "#");
console.log(res);

=> "this is a #test'"
```

for the second case :

```
var str = '"this is a \'test\'"';
var res = str.replace(/(.*(?='))'/, "$1#");
console.log(res);

=> "this is a 'test#"
```

Also understand that the second case is taking into consideration only the last `'`
and the first case will only consider the first `'`.

update:

if you want to replace all the occurence of the first `'` with something try this:

```
var str = '"this is a \'test\' there is another \'test\'"';
var res = str.replace(/'(\w)/g, "#$1");
console.log(res);

=> "this is a #test' there is another #test'"
```

for the second occurence try this:

```
var str = '"this is a \'test\' there is another \'test\'"';
var res = str.replace(/(\w)'/g, "$1#");
console.log(res);

=> "this is a 'test# there is another 'test#"
```

This ofcourse is a very manipulative approach and you may face exceptions cropping here and there. IMHO usage of regex and doing this in itself is an over complicated approach

Comment: This is promising but wont find all occurence of `'` in the string. As mentioned in comments OP expects `"this is a 'test' there is another 'test'"` as input as well. here it finds only the first occurence

Comment: Better now. And if you dont mind please dont call me sir am not that old :P

Answer (score 3):

**First  case**

```
/'\b/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sM3cT5/2)

```
"this is a 'test' there is another 'test'".replace(/'\b/g, '"'))
=> this is a "test' there is another "test'
```

**Second case**

```
/\b'/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sM3cT5/1)

```
"this is a 'test' there is another 'test'".replace(/\b'/g, '"'))
=> this is a 'test" there is another 'test"
```

Comment: @AliNaciErdem Its a great tool but it supports javascript only where as regex101 support php and python as well

Answer (score 1):

Depence on the string, for the given string `"this is a ->'<-test'"`

```
"this is a ->'<-test'".replace(/'/g,"\""); // does both at the same time
// output "this is a ->"<-test""
"this is a ->'<-test'".replace(/'/,"\"").replace(/'/,"\"") // or in two steps
// output "this is a ->"<-test""
// tested with Chrome 38+ on Win7
```

the `g` in the first Version, does a global replace so it replaces all `'` with `\"` (the Backslash is only the Escape Character). The second Version replaces only the first occurence.

I hope this helps

If you really, want match once the first and once the last(without selecting/replacing the first) you would have to do something like this:

```
"this is a ->'<-test'".replace(/'/,"\""); // the first stays the same
// output "this is a ->"<-test'"
"this is a ->'<-test'".replace(/(?!'.+)'/,"\""); // the last
// output "this is a ->'<-test""
// tested with Chrome 38+ on Win7
```